# jQuery focus sometimes ends up making the blinking text cursor disappear

Tags: jquery, html, input, cursor

Anyone know why `.focus()` makes the cursor go away but it comes back when you click in the text input box?

Answer (score 0):

[`.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) can't determine the cursor position, for example *where* should the cursor be when you fire the `focus` event on the element?  It's determined by where you `click`, which is a different event altogether.

Aside from that, when you [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) an event ([`.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) is a shortcut for [`.trigger('focus')`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)) it doesn't replicate the event the same as it would happen if the user created the event, e.g. the default action....for example the cursor position setting ([`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) won't work either, for this same reason).  [The jQuery docs for `.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) cover this briefly:

> While [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) simulates an event activation, complete with a synthesized event object, it does not perfectly replicate a naturally-occurring event.

You can *stop* the default action (with [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)), but there is no mechanism in jQuery core for creating or executing it.